# XML issue with one field - field does not have blank space (maybe tab or problematic encoding?)

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xml-encoding

I have XML file and within it one field with value from two words 
for example:

```
<NAME>INTERNET WEB</NAME>
```

When this is imported in some database this value is not saved like INTERNET WEB although on the first sight it looks exactly the same value in the database !!!

But it seems it does not have one blank space between the words INTERNET and WEB although as I mentioned it seems it is that value. Like it has something else instead of that but difference is not visible.

Problem is that I cannot filter that field with value INTERNET WEB because it seems it is not stored like that.
So what can be the problem? This XML file I received from some another external system.

How can I determine if this value has for example tab instead of blank space or it was encoded from some inappropriate format (UTF-8 is on the top of the XML file

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`)

I did the "Check XML syntax" in Notepad++ and it says No errors detected so XML is in OK format.

Comment: open this file in any hex editor and examine its contents?

Comment: can I use Notepad++? what action should be used?